# Downgrading Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, version, downgrade

I want to Downgrade my google chrome version 37 to chrome version 36 or 35 for some purposes. Ive been Disabling the Google Update Services from  services.msc and downloaded a stand alone versions but its still updating.

I also been through_HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update "Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"_ and set the values to zero and I also tried to add Google update administrative template on local group editor. But it is still updating

Can someone help me guys

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same because the updates were failing with an error 7 (group policy editor) and none of the suggested resolutions worked.  I was hosed and dug for quite a while this evening.  Take a look at this and see if it helps:

[How to disable silent and automatic updates in Chrome for Windows](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/disable-chrome-automatic-updates/)

Comment: Did you successfully installed chrome version 35?

Comment: And did you find an online installer for chrome 35? I searched for it then came up with and exe file(800+kb) I disconnected my internet so it cant find updates. But installing the version 35 will fail because it requires internet